# Multiple Serializers in a Serializer for ListApiView

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a condition wheree user should be able to do retrive or update on the data on the same endpoint.

I am trying to achieve something like this,  but since I am new to DRF I am not able to achieve this.

```py
class Meter_Detail_Serialzer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    site = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Meter_detail
        fields = '__all__'

class Current_supplies_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Current_supplies
        fields ="__all__"

class New_supplies_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = New_supplies
        fields = "__all__"


class SupplyDetail_Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
    
    meter_detail = Meter_Detail_Serialzer()
    current_supplies = Current_supplies_Serializer()
    new_supplies = Current_supplies_Serializer()
```

I am struggling how should I write the view for this, so that the data should look like...

```json
{
  "meter_detail": [1,2,3],
  "current_supplies": [1,2,3],
  "new_supplies":[1,2,3]
}
```

```py
class supply_detail(generics.ListAPIView):
    
    queryset = Meter_detail.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Meter_Detail_Serialzer
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']

        return  qs.filter(id=pk)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Models

```
from django.models import Model


class Meter(models.Model):
   # all your attributes
   pass


class Supply(models.Model):
   # all your attributes
   pass


class SupplyMeter(models.Model):
   supply = models.ForeignKey(Supply, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   meter = models.ForeignKey(Meter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

### Serializers

```
from rest_framework import serializer

from .models import Meter, Supply, SupplyMeter


class MeterSerialzer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    site = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Meter
        fields = '__all__'


class SupplySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Supply
        fields ="__all__"


class SupplyMeterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)

    supply = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        read_only = True,
        view_name = 'supply-detail',
    )
    meter = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        read_only = True,
        view_name = 'meter-detail',
    )    

    class Meta:
        model = SupplyMeter
        fields = '__all__'
```

### Views

```
from rest_framework.generics import (
    ListCreateAPIView,
    RetrieveAPIView
    RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView,
)

from .serializer import MeterSerializer, SupplySerializer, SupplyMeterSerializer

from .models import Meter, Supply


class MeterListView(ListAPIView):
    model = Meter
    queryset = model.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MeterSerialzer


class MeterSingleView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    model = Meter
    queryset = model.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MeterSerialzer


class SupplyListView(ListAPIView):
    model = Supply
    queryset = model.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SupplySerialzer


class SupplySingleView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    model = Supply
    queryset = model.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SupplySerialzer


class SupplyMeterDetailView(RetrieveAPIView):
    model = SupplyMeter
    queryset = model.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SupplyMeterSerializer
```

### Routers (routers.py app level)

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import (
    MeterListView,
    MeterSingleView,
    SupplyListView,
    SupplySingleView,
    SupplyMeterDetailView,
)


urlpatterns = [
   path('meters', MeterListView.as_view(), name='supplies'),
   path('meters/<int:pk>', MeterSingleView.as_view(), name='meter-detail'),
   path('supplies', SupplyListView.as_view(), name='supplies'),
   path('supplies/<int:pk>', SupplySingleView.as_view(), name='supply-detail'),

   path('supply-metter/<int:pk>', SupplyMeterDetail.as_view(), name='supply-meter-detail'),
]
```

## Routers (urls.py project level)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('<appname>.api.routers')),
]

# replace <appname> for the name of your app
```

## Explanation

I have created a total of four endpoints

1. `supplies`
2. `supplies/{supplyID}`
3. `meters`
4. `meters/{meterId}`

`supplies` and `meters` accept both `GET` and `POST` for listing and creating new elements.

`supplies/{supplyId}` and `meters/{meterId}` accept `PUT`, `PATCH`, and `DELETE` for update, partial update and delete respectively.

### Edit explanation

For the endpoint that you want to build...

> I have a web page where I want to show the details of supply and meter but the thing is I dont want to hit multiple endpoints for that - **amit patel**

I added an additional endpoint `supply-meter/<int:pk>` that would retrieve the detail of an instance of `SupplyMeter` model, which contains `many-to-one` relationship with the models `Supply` and `Meter`. The serializer for this model will retrieve the data for each relationship using the endpoints named `supply-detail` and `meter-detail` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this, I will go through the PEP8. But I am looking for one endpoint where I will get the details of the Meter and Supply for a particular instance. So when I pass in id as pk in url I should get the supply and meter details in one response. I have a web page where I want to show the details of supply and meter but the thing is I dont want to hit multiple endpoints for that.

Comment: Well, you could create a new endpoint that serializes both Supply and Meter details. I would edit my previous answer to give you an example.

Comment: But, if you only want to pass an Id in the URL, you would have to create either one model for both Supply and Serializer or another model that creates a relationship with both Supply and Meter by perhaps a ForeignKey relationship.

Comment: Please check the code above (have been edited). I'll be waiting for your feedback.

Comment: I'm glad it helped, Amit. Best of lucks in your journey! |m|